# SSH setting for mac to create an alias

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-tunnel

ssh address I want to alias is

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@hostipaddress@jumpServerAdress.com`

I am populating in the MAC ~/.ssh/config as

```
Host prod
  HostName hostipaddress
  User usrname
  ServerAliveInterval 100
  ProxyJump jumpServerAdress.com
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  GlobalKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

When I do `ssh prod`..
**it is not letting me inside the host**

It signals me:

```
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Is there any mistake in the config I am doing please let me know ?

Comment: Is `ssh - o ...` a typo for `ssh -o ...`?

Comment: Also, is the change from `jumpServerAdress.com` to `ServerAdress.com` intentional?

Comment: I edited that was a typo, when modifying the actual IP addresses @chepner

Comment: From the host called `prod`, can you `ping` by name the machine you are sitting at?

Comment: I can ping, 

PING XXXXXXXXXXXXX: 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
.
.@MarkSetchell

Comment: @hellopa1, could you check if port 22 is open your target machine.

`nmap -p 22 <hostipaddress>`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this config which worked

```
Host jump
  HostName jumpServerAdress.com
  User jumpuser

Host prod
  HostName hostipaddress
  User usrname
  ServerAliveInterval 100
  ProxyJump jump
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  GlobalKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

assuming you have setup ssh keys correctly.